# IF ELSE statements both are getting executed on click of a link in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a student table, if the student is pass then i want to delete the record from the table on a click on link otherwise not and for that i am checking status and showing popup. But in both the cases it is showing me both the popup.

Bellow is my **anchor tag :**

```
<a data-dialog-href="#" id="delete-@Model.StudentId" href="#" data-status="@Model.Status">Delete</i></a>
```

and **Jquery** :

```
<script>
    jQuery('body').on('click', '[data-dialog-href]', function (e) {

        var studentStatus = jQuery(this).attr('data-status'); 

        if (studentStatus  == "Completed") {
            $("#dialog-delete").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                title: "Confirm Delete",
                height: 250,
                width: 400,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function (e) {
                        $("dialog-confirm").css("display: block");
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#dialog-ok").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                title: "Inforamtion",
                height: 250,
                width: 400,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        $("dialog-confirm").css("display: block");
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**div for popup** :

```
<div id="dialog-delete">
    Are you sure you want to Delete Student?
</div>

<div id="dialog-ok">
    The student is not pass, Cant Delete this student.
</div>
```

dialog-ok is getting executed first then dialog-delete.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check in dev tools of your browser the value of `data-status` attribute?

Comment: may be case-sensitive comparison try with `status.toLowerCase() == "completed"`

Comment: replace if (status == "Completed") { to  if(studentStatus === "Completed"){

Comment: typo error `studentStatus` and `status`

Comment: what is `$("dialog-confirm")` ?? without any `selector` ???

Comment: it is not allowing me to use studentStatus.toLowerCase() @Satpal

Comment: $("dialog-confirm") is a css class @ParthTrivedi

Comment: the data-status is showing correct value @gurvinder372

Comment: in that case use `$(".dialog-confirm")`

Comment: @shivanisurana if it is a class selector then i should be `$(".dialog-confirm")` instead of `$("dialog-confirm")` :)

Comment: Yeah I did the corrections and now it is working fine. Thank You!

Comment: @shivanisurana use @ to comment out particular person. So person get notified.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I'll keep it in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting value in **studentStatus** variable and you are using **status** variable in the rest of your code.

Comment: i have made the corrections but still not working i as want.

Comment: Can you alert studentStatus and tell what the value is?

Comment: Also replace  $("dialog-confirm") with $("#dialog-confirm") or if its a class give $(".dialog-confirm")

Comment: What value did you get when you alerted studentStatus ?

Comment: @Ray I have done two changes $(".dialog-confirm").css("display: block"); and if(projectStatus == "Completed") and now it is working.